# Left Join Performance with addtional Left Table Filter

Tags: sql, performance, join, multiple-conditions

Hi I am wondering if putting additional conditions in left joing will improve performance.
Example Code is below.
I only need to know the Price data for certain offers but will need need all offers data.
Just wondering if it's worth putting the additional join conditions to speed up performance?

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    OFFERS 
LEFT JOIN PRICE ON (
    PRICE.PH_SUBS_LINK_SK = ACTSUBS.PH_SUBS_LINK_SK and 
    PRICE.PRICE_END_DT= '09-09-9999' and
    OFFERS.PERCENT_VALUE >0 and 
    OFFERS.VALUE_OR_PERCENT = 'PERCENT' and 
    OFFERS.PRODUCT_OFFER_TYPE = 'RC' and 
    OFFERS.OFFER_STATUS_CODE in ('ACT','PTM')
    )
```

Comment: Those are not join conditions, but filters.. filtering the data does give better performance in general, but it depends on indexes, partitions etc.

Comment: It's going to be dependent on the data-set sizes indexes and various other factors, it's not just the use of `JOIN` vs `WHERE` that will affect performance. Firstly `IN('ACT','PTM')` can often be quite inefficient and is often quicker as `(columnName = '' OR columnName = '')`. You also might get more help from http://dba.stackexchange.com/ as, although I believe your question is also applicable here, they might have more in depth knowledge on optimisation :)

Comment: Also it depends which RDBMS are you using.. did you compare execution plans?

Comment: You also are referencing ACTSUBS table, but no such table listed in your from or left-join.  That SHOULD give you a failed command to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change above code for this:

```
    SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    OFFERS 
LEFT JOIN PRICE ON
    PRICE.PH_SUBS_LINK_SK = ACTSUBS.PH_SUBS_LINK_SK 
WHERE PRICE.PRICE_END_DT= '09-09-9999' and
    OFFERS.PERCENT_VALUE >0 and 
    OFFERS.VALUE_OR_PERCENT = 'PERCENT' and 
    OFFERS.PRODUCT_OFFER_TYPE = 'RC' and 
    OFFERS.OFFER_STATUS_CODE in ('ACT','PTM')
```

To improve performance create an index for the fields used on the where statement.

Comment: This is not equivalent to original query because of the filter on outer-joined price table, which will now remove all rows where `PRICE_END_DT = '09-09-9999'` condition is not satisfied. Original query would return null rows instead of non-matching prices.